# How do I input whitespaces and any other unicode and outputing the same value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def A1Z26_decrypt(decrypt):
    string = ""     
    data = decrypt.split("-")

    for char in data:       
        char = chr(int(char) + 64)  
        string += char      
        return (string)
def main():
    lmfao = input("  ")
    print(A1Z26_decrypt(lmfao))
main()
```

I am trying to create a decrypt cipher that converts number inputs to letters. ie):1 -> A & 26 ->Z.
The code above is what I have so far when I input a number connected with a "-" the output is perfectly fine however when I try to enter a space in between it gives "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '14 13'". How could I make the code output without any errors when whitespace and other Unicode like ',",! @,#,$,% are involved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only convert number string to an integer ("10" to 10). But you can't do this: "@10" to 10. It doesn't make any sense. You will have to remove all non-numbers from the string which I think is not a good idea.

Comment: A regular expression split can do that: `data = re.split('[^0-9]+', decrypt)`. If there are non-digit characters at begin or end of the string, the returned list also contains an empty string or two.